# how to remove all elements pertaining to a class EXJs

Tags: extjs

I want to remove elements with a class named "some-class", I'm getting all the divs pertaining to that class using:

```
Ext.query('.some-class)
```

outputs:
array of divs: 
[.., ..]

how to remove them all, I tired applying `removeAll()` on the `Ext.query()`, but didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`Ext.select('.foo').remove();`

The `select` calls wraps it to allow you to call `Ext.Element` methods.